# Induced map (Isomorphism)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that $f: V \rightarrow W$ and $g: V \rightarrow W$ with finite rank. (linear maps)

So, one step of the suggestion of my professor I'm following for a problem related to $f$ and $g$ is to analyze the following.

Let $H : V \rightarrow V \times V/ker g$. Where $H(v) = (v,v + kerg)$. I have to show that $H$ is injective which I already did and also that the projection $ V \times V/ker g \rightarrow V/kerg$ induces an isomorphism between $coker(H)$ and $V/kerg$.

I don't know what does it means that induces an isomorphism (how?).

If you need more context, please write a comment, but I don't think so.

Comment: Is the first argument of $H$ $f(v)$ instead of $v$? Otherwise where do you use $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If the linear map $f:A \to B$ is surjective, then (by the first isomorphism theorem) it *induces* the isomorphism $\tilde f: A/(\ker f) \to B$.